# Implement an automatic reminder email feature for web based application

Tags: php, html, web-applications, cron, email

I would like to create a feature for my web application that once a user is entered in my database, every 4 weeks an email is sent to them reminding them to, for example, give some feedback. I've heard cron job is what Im looking for but Im curious what else is out there, is there maybe a php script that exists or an easy way to do it?

I want something like a countdown from once they enter the database to start counting down till 4 weeks has passed then call a php file or something that sends an email of my choosing to them. if this is possible let me know! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say to use a cron job (it could run everyday at a certain time that would be good to send an email), and the cron job could call a php script that would look through all your users and check when they signed up, and see if anyone signed up 4 weeks ago (or some multiple of that).  For anyone who meets this condition, you could go through a loop and send them emails with the mail() function.

**Cron Job**

Log into a shell on your server and type "sudo crontab -e" and type in something like this:

```
30 14 * * * php path/to/some/phpscript.php
```

In this example, phpscript.php is going to be run at 14:30 every day (2:30 pm).  But that doesn't mean it's going to email all the users every day!  See the script below.

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
# get all users (or your query could choose only users who signed up (4 weeks)*n ago)
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user');
$users = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $users[] = $row;

# loop through users and (if you didn't already check) see which ones have signed up (4 weeks)*n ago
foreach ($users as $user) {
    # take the number of seconds and convert it to number of days
    $today = (int)(strtotime(date('c')) / 60 / 60 / 24);
    $signup_day = (int)(strtotime($user['signup_date']) / 60 / 60 / 24);
    # check if the amount of days since signup is a multiple of 28 (4*7)
    if (($today - $signup_day) && ($today - $signup_day) % 28 == 0) {
        send_mail_to($user);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok this ^^ sounds like what I need! but Im a bit confused...even though it runs at 230 everyday it technically isnt? why is that?

Comment: It would run the script at 2:30 everyday, but the script itself checks all the users and dates and ONLY sends the right emails.

Comment: I see....is that very efficient that it runs everyday?  or is that pretty much the best option.....

Comment: It's not inefficient to run a tiny script of 30 lines once a day.  Computers can run millions of lines of code a day without breaking a sweat!

Comment: Well, I use free popular hosting, which offers database as well. I would say their hardware resources are such a crap, so I don't mind making cronjob to run daily rather than every 1 minute :D