# Delay sending email in phpMailer

Tags: php, email, delay, phpmailer

I was just thinking of creating a reminder page where any user can enter his email, name, subject and a date so that an email will be send to him one day earlier than the date selected.

I need to use phpMailer since I'm using it for all of my contact forms.

Is there a way to delay sending an email based on the user's input in the date section?

### *Update

My fears caught up to me, it appears I have no other choice than to use a Cron job, ok, fine then. (or not so fine since I haven't done it before)

I create a cron job that runs my script every day at 12:30

```
30 12 * * * php path/to/some/phpscript.php
```

Using cPanel
[image]

But say one user wants to be emailed on 24th of March 2016, so his input will be like `24/3/2016`

How do I check today's date to see if it's one day before the user's specified date, and if it is, run the PHP mailer script.

### *Last Edit with working solution

I made two pages, one that has a comment form with a datepicker, another that lists the comments and goes through all of them, checks to see if current date == datepicker then hit phpMailer with the fields in the comment as subject, recipient and so on. Then made a cron job to access the page everyday at 7:30 and it's working like a charm !

Comment: You're probably looking for a cron job, combine that with a database of events.

Comment: @Qirel Well, that's probably true, but I never created a cron job, therefore I needed someone to kick my ass in the right direction :)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634089/implement-an-automatic-reminder-email-feature-for-web-based-application), it's not exactly the same - but you can use that to get started. ;)

Comment: @Qirel , that would be a start, thank you, but how would I get the email sent on the day the user specifies ?

Comment: *"But say one user wants to be emailer on 24th of March 2016, so his input will be like 24/3/2016"* - You could use a database and with a trigger.

Comment: @Fred-ii- wouldn't I have to auto-create a trigger for every user that wants a reminder ?

Comment: @Alin The trigger I added after in an edit. After a bit of reflection, don't use a trigger. You could setup a db with a date/datetime column as a "reminder" date. The cron job on the db file would pick up on the date, when comparing to `if(date==x){ // do something }` type of thing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thinking about it, for this project I am using couchCms, I could create a php page and compare today's date with the date in the input, and if those two are the same, send the email using phpMailer. Also, use a cron job to run the script every day.

Comment: @Alin I don't know about couchCms but am under the impression that could work, in the way you've explained it, sure.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am coding the page right now, will see if it works and maybe come back tomorrow (after testing it) to post some code and give some feedback. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Alin You're welcome, *cheers* @ me to see if you were successful. Good luck :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I made two pages, one that has a comment form with a datepicker, another that lists the comments and goes through all of them, checks to see if current date == datepicker  then hit phpMailer with the fields in the comment as subject, recipient and so on. Then made a cron job to access the page everyday at 7:30 and it's working like a charm ! :D

Comment: @Alin right on, glad to hear it worked out for you. Resourceful and fast too, very cool, *cheers*

Answer (score -3):

> Yes, absolutely there is a  function on php  by specifying the number of seconds is sleep(s)

Comment: Do you really think sleep() is the best way of doing this?...and, say the user added the reminder to 27th of March, 2016. How would that go?

Comment: `sleep()` only works when the called page is executed, and not done automatically. Do respond to @Alin's comment here. If you can't answer them with a proper solution, then delete this answer; it's incorrect which is why you received those downvotes.